# cosmos db RequestRateTooLargeException

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

I am trying to insert a number of vertices and edges in Azure Cosmos DB but keep getting the exception

RequestRateTooLargeException

I have set my throughput to 2000 and when I look at my average throughput for the last minute I get maximum about 120 RU/s.

I am wondering if there is a setting somewhere that I have missed or if I have just misunderstood how the throughput is counted and regulated.

[Monitor view after triggering script that gets exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS1iI.png)

[Throughput after script that gets exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9CZb.png)

[Graph setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIcDz.png)

Comment: is your collection partitioned?

Comment: @OlgaShumeliuk yes I have a partition on _id

Comment: how many paratitions do you have? Thoughput is divided between all partition key ranges. You can see how many partition key ranges you have and RU for it in cosmos db / metrics / throughput tab

Comment: @OlgaShumeliuk I only have one partition key

Comment: I just added a screenshot of my monitoring after I triggered the script that gets the exception.

Comment: can you post screenshot of whole Throughput tab for your collection? Are you sure you set 2k RUs for collection?

Comment: @OlgaShumeliuk I have now added the screen of the throughput and the settings. The problem is that it displays the throughput for a minute and the setting is per second.

Comment: it seems like only 1 of 200 your request fail with RequestRateTooLargeException - not so big deal if you have retry policy. Maybe graph with Max consumed RU/s isn't very accurate. According to your first screenshot - take into account that those values are immediate values (but with some delay in 2-3 min) According to metrics your max RU/s is around 2K RU

Comment: Ok, thanks!  I will try with the retry policy. Looks like I have to build it myself when using gremlin.